# compute percentiles from histogram data

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following table captures student grade data over a number of exams.

```
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| name    |  exams |  grade_poor |  grade_fair |  grade_good |  grade_vgood |
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| arun    |      8 |           1 |           4 |           2 |            1 |
| neha    |     10 |           3 |           2 |           1 |            4 |
| ram     |      5 |           1 |           1 |           3 |            0 |
| radha   |      8 |           0 |           3 |           1 |            4 |
+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

the grades are ordered and have the following numeric values

```
+-------------+--------+
|    grade    |  value |
+-------------+--------+
| grade_poor  |      0 |
| grade_fair  |      1 |
| grade_good  |      2 |
| grade_vgood |      3 |
+-------------+--------+
```

Need to find the 50th percentile grade for each student in value terms as in the table below.

```
+-------+--------+------------------+
| grade |  exams |  grade_perc50th  |
+-------+--------+------------------+
| arun  |      8 |                1 |
| neha  |     10 |              1.5 |
| ram   |      5 |                2 |
| radha |      8 |              2.5 |
+-------+--------+------------------+
```

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42547358/3206440), but different - not an exact duplicate as marked.

Comment: If you want to provide more information to your original question **edit** _that_ question. Don't ask a new question.

Comment: sorry, the questions are related, but different - can you check again ?