# merge multiple columns into an array

Tags: sql, netezza

In `PostgreSQL` we can use `array[col1, col2, col3]` to merge multiple columns into an array - this is not working in `Netezza`. What is the right way to do this in Netezza ?

Postgres SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f53f1/4)

I'm trying to implement the Postgres answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42570589/3206440)

Answer (score 0):

You should download the Netezza SQL Extensions Toolkit which includes functions like the array functions.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/beta/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_array.html