# percentiles from histogram data for discrete values

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to implement the following PostgreSQL code in Netezza. This basically computes the percentiles from a histogram data for discrete values. The Postgres question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42547358/3206440).

```
CREATE TABLE grades
AS
  SELECT name, exams, grade_poor, grade_fair, grade_good, grade_vgood
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 'arun'  , 8  , 1 , 4 , 2 , 1 ),
    ( 'neha'  , 10 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 4 ),
    ( 'ram'   ,  5 , 1 , 1 , 3 , 0 ),
    ( 'radha' ,  8 , 0 , 3 , 1 , 4 )
  ) AS t(name,exams,grade_poor,grade_fair,grade_good,grade_vgood);

SELECT name, percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY gs1.x)
FROM (
  SELECT name,
    ARRAY[grade_poor, grade_fair, grade_good, grade_vgood]
  FROM grades
) AS t(name, grades)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1,4) AS gs1(x)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1,grades[gs1.x]) AS gs2(x)
GROUP BY name ORDER BY name;
```

Code can be ran [here](http://rextester.com/live/VTSP33905)

The resulting output is

```
 name  | percentile_disc 
-------+-----------------
 arun  |               2
 neha  |               2
 radha |               3
 ram   |               3
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Netezza supports `percentile_disc()`.  So the major issue is unpivoting the data:

```
SELECT name, percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY grade)
FROM ((SELECT name, grade_poor as grade
       FROM grades
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT name, grade_fair as grade
       FROM grades
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT name, grade_good as grade
       FROM grades
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT name, grade_vgood as grade
       FROM grades
      )
     ) g
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: this gives the 50th percentile for the grades "count", but the idea in the question was to have the 50th percentile for the grade "value" - see output in question.