# un-pivot histogram data of discrete values

Tags: sql, netezza

With a table `grades` that holds histogram of grades for students like below, need to *unpivot* it converting the column names into indices.

```
CREATE TABLE grades
AS
  SELECT name, exams, grade_poor, grade_fair, grade_good, grade_vgood
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 'arun'  , 8  , 1 , 4 , 2 , 1 ),
    ( 'neha'  , 10 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 4 ),
    ( 'ram'   ,  5 , 1 , 1 , 3 , 0 ),
    ( 'radha' ,  8 , 0 , 3 , 1 , 4 )
  ) AS t(name,exams,grade_poor,grade_fair,grade_good,grade_vgood);
```

The grades can be indexed to numeric values - for example  as below.

```
+-------------+--------+
|    grade    |  value |
+-------------+--------+
| grade_poor  |      1 |
| grade_fair  |      2 |
| grade_good  |      3 |
| grade_vgood |      4 |
+-------------+--------+
```

**Expected output**

```
+-------+-------+
| name  | grade |
+-------+-------+
| arun  |     1 |
| arun  |     2 |
| arun  |     2 |
| arun  |     2 |
| arun  |     2 |
| arun  |     3 |
| arun  |     3 |
| arun  |     4 |
| neha  |     1 |
| neha  |     1 |
| neha  |     1 |
| neha  |     2 |
| neha  |     2 |
| neha  |     3 |
| neha  |     4 |
| neha  |     4 |
| neha  |     4 |
| neha  |     4 |
| radha |     2 |
| radha |     2 |
| radha |     2 |
| radha |     3 |
| radha |     4 |
| radha |     4 |
| radha |     4 |
| radha |     4 |
| ram   |     1 |
| ram   |     2 |
| ram   |     3 |
| ram   |     3 |
| ram   |     3 |
+-------+-------+
```

The question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42570589/3206440) shows the postgres way of doing it.

Comment: are names unique or is there an id column?

Comment: @GurV they can be considered uniq.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with up_grades as (
    select
        g.name,
        x.i grade_type,
        case x.i
            when 1 then grade_poor
            when 2 then grade_fair
            when 3 then grade_good
            when 4 then grade_vgood
        end grades
    from grades g
    cross join (
        select 1 i union all
        select 2 i union all
        select 3 i union all
        select 4 i  
    ) x
) 
select g.name, g.grade_type
from up_grades g
join (
    select level n
    connect by 
        level <= (select max(grades) from up_grades)
) c on g.grades >= c.n
order by g.name, g.grade_type;
```

Inside the CTE, we unpivoting the table i.e. converting the columns into rows. Then, we are using hierarchical queries to generating as many rows are there are grades for a give name and grade type.

<sub>Disclaimer- [Tested only on Oracle](http://rextester.com/SLIFU9496) (after adding the required dual table in places) as the syntax mostly matches. Untested on Netezza.</sub>

Comment: Netezza dosen't support hierarchical queries

Comment: @NzGuy - This site says otherwise - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2033.htm

Comment: Recursive queries are not supported by netezza as of now 7.2.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_with_clause.html

Comment: @NzGuy - Where exactly did I use recursion?

Comment: `connect by` dosent support in Netezza as of now 7.2